# How can I embed a link into a photo to be shared on Facebook, like Dropbox app does with FB photo share?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I embed a link (and message) into a photo being shared on Facebook by a user of an iOS app? Dropbox automatically does this when sharing a photo to Facebook from their app.

Pre-post screenshot in Dropbox App:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxoMvrZdDAViY29YTm1kOFVjZTQ/view

Result as posted on Facebook:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxoMvrZdDAViNE5sbWw3WmstZ1E/view

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set og:image and og:url meta tags on the page you want to share.

You can use the Facebook URL Linter / Debugger to verify/inspect the meta tags of your own page/URL or the DropBox URL from your example:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/